# Python, AWS Elasticsearch migration to Azure

Tags: python, azure, elasticsearch

I had this project completely built and pushed to AWS, the Elasticsearch queries worked great. Now I've authenticated with Azure. Created my index, and can do a simple "select all query" and get records back. But, when I try to get my original AWS elasticsearch query to work it just refuses to work.

Would you please help me fix my query?

AWS Code this code was working and in production on AWS. It is being retired as we move to Azure.

```py
def request_search():
  try:
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
      host = ''
      region = 'us-west-2'
      service = 'es'
      credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
      awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)
      
      es = Elasticsearch(
          hosts=[{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
          http_auth=awsauth,
          use_ssl=True,
          verify_certs=True,
          connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
      )

      search_term = request.form['input']
      res= es.search(index=myindex,  scroll = '2m', doc_type='_doc',body={
      "query": {
      "multi_match" : {
      "query":    search_term,
      "fields": [ "creator", "date", "receipt", "sales", "category"],
      "fuzziness" : "AUTO",
      "prefix_length" : 0
                      }
              }
      },
      size=1000)
      res['ST']=search_term 
      return render_template('results.html', res=res, search_term=search_term)
    else:
      #return to search page. 
      return render_template('index.html')

  except Exception as e:
    return render_template("404_generic", error = str(e))
```

Azure Code -- Does not work

```py
 if request.method == 'POST':
     #search_term = "Hotel"
     search_term = request.form['input']
     #print("The search term is: " + search_term)
     res= es.search(index="myindex", scroll = '2m', doc_type='_doc', query={
        "multi_match" : {
        "query":    "search_term",
        "fuzziness": 2,
        "fields": [ "creator", "date", "receipt", "sales", "category"],
        "fuzziness" : "AUTO",
        "prefix_length" : 0

        
        }
        },
        size=1000)
     res['ST']=search_term 
     return render_template('index.html',
                              res=res,
                              search_term=search_term                          
                            )
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I believe I was very specific. The one query runs on AWS. I'm migrating to Azure. The same Elasticsearch query which is supposed to work across clouds does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that I'm using Azure Cognitive Search for the migration from AWS to Azure, not specifically ElasticSearch. This guide has helped the migration and clear up confusion.

https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-search/1.0.0b1/index.html#